# SQL Server: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,2'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion

I have a query like this

```
select
    t.tiid, t.employeeid, t.remarks,
    dd.DocID, dd.Document, dd.DocuName
from
    ti t
inner join 
    History cth on cth.tiid = t.tiid
inner join 
    Downloads dd on dd.DocID = cth.DocID
```

My data in table is like this

History:

```
DocID            DocuName
1,2              abc.dox,def.docx
```

Downloads

```
DocID    DocuName         document
1        abc.docx         x3400000efg..
2        def.docx         xc445560000...
```

but when I execute this query, it shows an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,2' to data type int.

Comment: You should redesign your history table by the looks of things. Why are you storing values that should be in different rows comma delimited in a single row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DocID of history is multiple DocID had been combined with comma, So you can not compare the value directly( One value vs Multiple values).

You can check whether the multiple values contain the specify value use CHARINDEX.

To make sure complete matched of sub string,need a delimiter to indicate a single value, otherwise can get wrong result.
For Eample:
  CHARINDEX('1,','12,2,3') will be 1, but in fact, there is no 1 in the string.

```
select 
 t.tiid,
 t.employeeid,
 t.remarks,
 dd.DocID,
 dd.Document,
 dd.DocuName
from ti t
inner join History cth on cth.tiid=t.tiid
inner join Downloads dd on CHARINDEX(','+LTRIM(dd.DocID)+',',','+cth.DocID+',')>0
```

Comment: Upvoted for CHARINDEX use. But can you explain the logic of CharIndex instead of code in answer?

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you are trying to equate a string with int.You need to convert the int DocID as string and check if it's present in the comma-separated DocID .Something like

```
SELECT t.tiid,
       t.employeeid,
       t.remarks,
       dd.DocID,
       dd.Document,
       dd.DocuName
FROM ti t
INNER JOIN History cth ON cth.tiid=t.tiid
INNER JOIN Downloads dd ON CHARINDEX(',' + CAST(dd.DocID AS VARCHAR(10)) + ',',',' + cth.DocID + ',')>0
```